# Why would ">:i " work in the repl but not "> :t "?

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, repl

Doing week 04, watching "PPP 030403 - The EmulatorTrace Monad"

In the repl, having already imported as follows

> ```
> >import Data.Char
> >import Text.Read
> >import Plutus.Trace.Emulator
> >import Data.Default
> ```

If I enter ":t TraceConfig" I see

> ```
> Prelude Data.Char Text.Read Plutus.Trace.Emulator Data.Default> :t TraceConfig
> TraceConfig
>   :: (Wallet.Emulator.MultiAgent.EmulatorEvent' -> Maybe String)
>      -> GHC.IO.Handle.Types.Handle -> TraceConfig
> Prelude Data.Char Text.Read Plutus.Trace.Emulator Data.Default>
> ```

Attempting to explore that, I enter (and get error) as follows:

> ```
> Prelude Data.Char Text.Read Plutus.Trace.Emulator Data.Default> :t Wallet.Emulator.MultiAgent.EmulatorEvent'
>  
> :1:1: error:
>     Not in scope:
>       data constructor ‘Wallet.Emulator.MultiAgent.EmulatorEvent'’
>     No module named ‘Wallet.Emulator.MultiAgent’ is imported.
>  
>  
> Prelude Data.Char Text.Read Plutus.Trace.Emulator Data.Default> :i Wallet.Emulator.MultiAgent.EmulatorEvent'
> type Wallet.Emulator.MultiAgent.EmulatorEvent' :: *
> data Wallet.Emulator.MultiAgent.EmulatorEvent'
>   = Wallet.Emulator.MultiAgent.ChainEvent Wallet.Emulator.Chain.ChainEvent
>   | Wallet.Emulator.MultiAgent.ClientEvent Wallet.Emulator.Wallet.Wallet
>                                           Wallet.Emulator.NodeClient.NodeClientEvent
>   | Wallet.Emulator.MultiAgent.WalletEvent Wallet.Emulator.Wallet.Wallet
>                                          Wallet.Emulator.Wallet.WalletEvent
>   | Wallet.Emulator.MultiAgent.ChainIndexEvent Wallet.Emulator.Wallet.Wallet
>                                           plutus-chain-index-core-0.1.0.0:Plutus.ChainIndex.ChainIndexLog.ChainIndexLog
>   | Wallet.Emulator.MultiAgent.SchedulerEvent Plutus.Trace.Scheduler.SchedulerLog
>   | Wallet.Emulator.MultiAgent.InstanceEvent Plutus.Trace.Emulator.Types.ContractInstanceLog
>   | Wallet.Emulator.MultiAgent.UserThreadEvent Plutus.Trace.Emulator.Types.UserThreadMsg
>       -- Defined in ‘Wallet.Emulator.MultiAgent’
> instance Eq Wallet.Emulator.MultiAgent.EmulatorEvent'
>   -- Defined in ‘Wallet.Emulator.MultiAgent’
> instance Show Wallet.Emulator.MultiAgent.EmulatorEvent'
>   -- Defined in ‘Wallet.Emulator.MultiAgent’
> Prelude Data.Char Text.Read Plutus.Trace.Emulator Data.Default>
> ```

My question is, why does ":i" (requesting info about) work, but ":t" (requesting merely the type, which is actually included in the info) does not?
 
Tracking these multiple nestings of data structures is straining my brain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take into account that **:t** is for getting the type of a function, and **EmulatorEvent'** is not a function but a type. So, because it's a type you can use `:i EmulatorEvent'` but not `:t EmulatorEvent'`.

You can use **:t** with the constructors (they are functions) of **EmulatorEvent'**, say `:t ChainEvent`.

[image]

Comment: Part of me thinks this should "fail" gracefully, since the focus of the monad video was elegant failure.

Comment: What do you mean with fail gracefully? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @XiTouch, Do you consider that my answer is correct? I so, you might accept it and help others wiith the same question. Thanks!

Comment: your answer is helpful, correct, useful, the best offered, and the best ever likely to be offered so yes, it's "answered" and thank you. By "fail gracefully" I mean cabal should produce a message that is helpful and accurately informative, rather than basically "you screwed up, I won't help you, you should know better." For example, a message like "foo is not a type. Use {>:i foo} for info about foo".

Comment: @XiTouch, I agree that the message is not very helpful (in general Haskell error messages are not good), but this message doesn't come from cabal or Plutus. :t and :i is a ghci thing.